# Query string not passing to handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have Two tables in database in which there is field with type "Image" and in another table there are fields that i want to retrieve in FormView.
The formView shows fields from another table but not showing image in image control.
aspx file

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="ListStories" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" >
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr><td><%#Eval("Subject") %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%#Eval("Story") %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%#Eval("UserName")%> </td></tr>

</table>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl = '~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=<%#Eval("UserName") %>'  Width="150" Height="150" />
</ItemTemplate>


</asp:FormView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RetriveStories();

    }

    protected void RetriveStories()
    {

        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        cmdStories = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName, Subject, Story FROM Stories", conn);

        conn.Open();
        reader = cmdStories.ExecuteReader();


        ListStories.DataSource = reader;
        ListStories.DataBind();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

Image Handler:

```
public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Name"];

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(userName);
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            context.Response.WriteFile("img/default.png");
        }
    }

    public Stream ShowEmpImage(string name)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Alumnidb"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmdRetiveImage = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo FROM UserProfile WHERE UserName=@UserName", conn);
        cmdRetiveImage.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdRetiveImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", name);
        conn.Open();
        object img = cmdRetiveImage.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But Image Handler always execute these lines

```
catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                context.Response.WriteFile("img/default.png");
            }
```

Why its not working as i pass query string but still it executes null value?
Your help will be appreciated.Thanx

Comment: Someone Plz guide me what is wrong with that code. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
... ImageUrl = '~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=<%#Eval("UserName") %>' ...
```

with

```
... ImageUrl = '<%# "~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=" + Server.UrlEncode(Eval("UserName").ToString()) %>' ...
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

tyy this code. will help you

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string userName = context.Request.QueryString["Name"];

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(userName);
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            context.Response.WriteFile("img/default.png");
        }
    }
```

Comment: this line has issue => HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Name"];

Comment: Exactly but i cant figured it out as i manually add username it works fine but it's not working with query string

Comment: try with context.Request["Name"]

Comment: still not working. .. is some thing wrong with markup? as i passed query string from image control?

Comment: Did you try sending request directly to  your handler with query string from browser. Also check with browser developer tool to trace your request header if it's actually sending the query string parameter or not.

Comment: have you check your image URL has Name value in query sting  when you bind ?

Comment: i mean to say image URL from firebug or by debugging ?

Comment: I copied that url from browser after execute the project. . .Sorry if am not getting you

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl = '~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=<%#Eval("UserName") %>'  Width="150" Height="150" /> what is the url value of this image

Comment: http://localhost:1308/Alumuni/ShowImage.ashx?Name=%3C%#Eval("UserName") %>
I copied it from page source

Comment: Eval("UserName") why you use this ? UserName is your variable name ? you cnat not use server tag on asp control please assign on server side or use simple html image like <img tag>

Comment: I want to select photo from table where username is the name of user which is showing in form view

Comment: But the problem is showing image for null values as i mentioned in post and its also showing image when i hard code the username but not when using query string why query string is not passing to the handler?